# Estimating Pi using Monte Carlo simulations but without using fractional numbers

Tags: monte-carlo

Euler's number can be estimated by using an array of size $n$, randomly permuting it and checking whether it is a derangement or not. The simulation repeats this process several times and keeps track of how many times this permutation was not a derangement. This simulation does not require us to generate fractions.

This process is special in the sense that it uses **integers** to estimate an **irrational** number.

Is there a similar process to estimate the constant Pi, which uses only random integers or random permutations?

Let me illustrate what I **do not** want.
Pi can be estimated by picking random points in the square whose corner points are (-1,-1) (-1,1)(1,-1) and (1,1). We also draw a circle inside this square with radius 1 and origin as its center. Let $c$ be the number of points inside(or on) this circle and $s$ be the set of points which lie inside the square but outside the circle. $c/s$ approaches $\pi/4$. I do not want to use this method, because it requires me generate random fractional numbers in the range of -1 to 1, to generate these coordinates.

I hope my requirement is clear.

Comment: Your process is special in the sense that it doesn't actually estimate $e:$ it only estimates a rational number that is close to $e.$ You can estimate $1/e$ *accurately* (and then obtain $e$ easily) by repeatedly observing a Poisson$(1)$ variable and counting how many zeros appear: the proportion estimates $1/e.$ Would this "use integers"? What if you ran a Poisson process of rate $\log\pi$? Although that "uses integers," the process itself has a parameter explicitly determined by $\pi.$ What if we flipped a fair coin and exponentiated its mean to estimate $\sqrt{e}$ (which is irrational)?

Comment: What are you trying to say?
Can you please specify a technique which does not require creating random numbers in the range of [0,1) but it still creates good estimation of Pi?

Comment: I did! A Poisson process generates only integer values when you count the events in each successive unit interval.  And there are many other ways to estimate $\pi$ with proportions, even non-geometric ones.  For instance, literally any statistic with an asymptotically Normal distribution can be standardized and (therefore) its relative frequency near zero must approach $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ in large samples, giving an estimate of $\pi.$ Then there are the obvious--and essentially trivial--geometric methods in which you randomly sample a region, like a circle, whose area is related to $\pi.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Trivial -- but magical:**

```
BBP <- function(n = 13) {
  sum(sapply(seq_len(n), function(k) {
    ((sample.int(8*k+1, 1) <= 4) -
       (sample.int(8*k+4, 1) <= 2) -
       (sample.int(8*k+5, 1) <= 1) -
       (sample.int(8*k+6, 1) <= 1)) / 16^k
  })) + (4 - 2/4 - 1/5 - 1/6)
}
```

As you can see in this `R` code, only rational arithmetic operations (comparison, subtraction, division, and addition) are performed on the results of a small number of draws of *integral* values using `sample.int`.  By default, only $13*4=52$ draws are made (of values never greater than $110$) -- but the expected value of the result is $\pi$ to full double-precision!

Here is a sample run of $10,000$ iterations (requiring one second of time):

```
x <- replicate(1e4, BBP())
mu <- mean(x)
se <- sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))
signif(c(Estimate=mu, SE=se, Z=(mu-pi)/se), 4)
```

Its output is

> ```
>  Estimate        SE         Z 
> 3.1430000 0.0004514 2.0870000
> ```

In other words, this (random) estimate of $\pi$ is $3.143\pm 0.00045$ and the smallish Z-value of $2.08$ indicates this doesn't deviate significantly from the true value of $\pi.$

---

**This is trivial** because, as I hope the code makes obvious, calculations like `sample.int(b,1) <= a` (when the integer `a` does not exceed `b`) are just stupid ways to estimate the rational fractions `a/b`.  Thus, this code estimates the [Bailey Borwein Plouffe formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula)

$$\pi = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{16^k}\left(\frac{4}{8k+1}-\frac{2}{8k+4}-\frac{1}{8k+5}-\frac{1}{8k+6}\right)$$

by expressing the $k=0$ term explicitly and sampling all subsequent terms through $k=13.$  Since each term in the formula introduces $4$ additional bits in the binary expansion of $\pi,$ terminating the sampling at this point gives $4*(13)=52$ bits after the binary point, which is slightly more than the maximal $52$ *total* bits of precision available in the IEEE double precision floats used by `R`.

**Although we could work out the variance analytically,** the previous example already gives us a good estimate of it, because the standard error was only $0.0045,$ associated with a variance of $0.002$ per iteration.

```
var(x)
```

> ```
> [1] 0.002037781
> ```

Thus, if you would like to use `BBP` to estimate $\pi$ to within a standard error of $\sigma,$ you will need approximately $0.002/\sigma^2$ iterations.  For example, estimating $\pi$ to six decimal places in this manner will require around two billion iterations (about three days of computation).

One way to reduce the variance (greatly) would be to compute a few more of the initial terms in the BBP sum once and for all, using Monte Carlo simulation only to estimate the least significant bits of the result :-).

Comment: (+1): beautiful but I am unsure the "trivial" label applies!

Answer (score 2):

A simple method would be generating a pair of integers from $[0,M)$ and see if it's inside the quadrant, i.e. let the numbers be denoted as $m_1, m_2$. If $m_1^2+m_2^2<M^2$, the point is inside the quadrant. If the numbers were continuous, the probability would have been $\pi/4$. So, increasing $M$, increases the precision of the estimate. Below is a Python one liner:

```
N = int(1e8)
M = int(1e9)
4 * np.mean(np.sum(np.random.randint(0, M, (2, N))**2, axis=0) < M**2)
```

Comment: I am assuming that the numbers won't be continuous, because you are only choosing integers in that range. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes @Vk1, just integers. As $M$ increases, it'll behave *more* continuous

Comment: Wouldn't that require M to be extremely large. I am trying to create a code for estimating this value. Would the math work out? How do I say with ut most certainty that it will behave exactly like a continuous function. Kindly enlighten me with the proof or a place where I could look up such a topic.

Comment: You can use the above code snippet. Of course, like any other random experiment, the accuracy of a depends on parameters ($N$ and $M$)

Comment: It can't behave *exactly* as continuous. It'll get close to it via increasing $M$. Your method in estimating $e$ doesn't behave like continuous as well, as whuber's comment, it tries to approximate an irrational number via a rational number (as this  method).

Comment: I may not be satisfied with the solution, but I am very grateful for your comments. Maybe my question is not clear enough.

Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

To produce the probability $1/\pi$, the following algorithm can be used (Flajolet et al. 2010), which is based on a series expansion by Ramanujan:

1. Set $t$ to 0.
2. Flip two fair coins. If both show heads, add 1 to $t$ and repeat this step. Otherwise, go to step 3.
3. Flip two fair coins. If both show heads, add 1 to $t$ and repeat this step. Otherwise, go to step 4.
4. With probability 5/9, add 1 to $t$. (For example, generate a uniform random integer in [1, 9], and if that integer is 5 or less, add 1 to $t$.)
5. Flip a fair coin $2t$ times, and return 0 if heads showed more often than tails or vice versa. Do this step two more times.
6. Return 1.

Then, run the algorithm above until you get 1, then let $X$ be the number of runs including the last. Then the expected value of $X$ is $\pi$.

Note that the algorithm doesn't involve fractions at all.

See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4189867/obtaining-irrational-probabilities

REFERENCES:

- Flajolet, P., Pelletier, M., Soria, M., "[On Buffon machines and numbers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.5560.pdf)", arXiv:0906.5560 [math.PR], 2010.